# Sqlite3 in iPhone gives Database Locked Exception

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am newbiee in iphone and sqlite and doing some tutorials.

I have created one method which stores some temperory informartion into my database.

Now when i am on firstView controller of my Application i called that method twice. It stores the data twice into the particular table. Now i went to SecondViewController and in there i have a new sqlite3 object in the header file and i again copy paste that method into the SecondViewController. Now when i call that method on Second ViewController it gives me following error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while inserting data. 'database is locked''
```

my Code is:

```
-(void)storeTemp
```

{

```
SchoolFocusIPadAppDelegate *delegate = (SchoolFocusIPadAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sfocusDB.sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &databases) == SQLITE_OK){

    //const char *sql = "select * from animal";
    const char *sql = "insert into groups(id, groupid, name, desc , createdon,createdby) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *add;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databases, sql, -1, &add, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
        NSLog(@"***Storing START on Database ***");
        sqlite3_bind_text(add, 2, [[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Temp Group Dont Open"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(add, 3, [[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"kjhasd"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(add, 4, [[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"asdas"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(add, 5, [[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"asdsa"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(add, 6, [[NSString  stringWithFormat:@""] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"***Storing END on Database ***");
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(add))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(databases));
        else {
            NSLog(@"YES THE DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
    }
  sqlite3_finalize(add);
}
sqlite3_close(databases);
}
```

Please Help me friends. M really stucked.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some problems with sqlite3_close following an if/else (not sure why) but when I also put the finalize and close calls *inside* the if, it'd work out. I started following every open and close with an NSLog of the same (numbered so I knew which one was which) and you can then see which step left the DB open (and therefore locked)

Comment: damn thas was my mistake.... I forgot to close the DB on one of my methods.. when i follow each and every method which interacts with my DB then i found that.. Thanks for advice. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
here lots of chances to kill 
1.if your id is not null in DB it will kill with constraint failed error

if you don't want to insert any value to id remove from list 
like
const char *sql = "insert into groups( groupid, name, desc , createdon,createdby) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and change that number 1-5 instead of 2-6

Comment: id is a primary key and auto increment value. So that is why i am not adding its value. and I tried by removing Id from insert query but still that error occurs.. :(

Comment: are you changed 2-6 numbers to 1-5

Comment: once debug with break point after that tell me on which statement app kill

Comment: it actually executes all the sqlite_bind_text statments but when it comes on sqlite_step It does not give SQLITE_DONE so it comes to inside if and show the assertion error mesage. with the exception i pasted in my question

Comment: damn thas was my mistake.... I forgot to close the DB on one of my methods.. when i follow each and every method which interacts with my DB then i found that.. Thanks for advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the database to the writable doc-dir?

Your prepare-call needs a little change:

From `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databases, sql, -1, &add, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){`

To `if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databases, [sql UTF8String], -1, &add, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){`

(but that's nit the reason for the `database locked`).